# Programa parou de Responder - c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Estou fazendo um programa em c# que, basicamente, faz consultas (grandes) a um banco de dados MySql. Quando executo o programa via Visual Studio, tudo ocorre perfeitamente. 
Mas, quando o faço pelo executável, quando o botão que realiza as consultas e as trata é pressionado, o aplicativo para de responder. Mesmo travando, depois de um tempo o programa apresenta o resultado. Todavia, gostaria que desse para acompanhar o progresso via barra de progresso.

Como sou "programador" apenas nas hora vagas, programo tudo de forma simples, utilizando pouco as funcionalidades mais complexas da linguagem. Por isso, gostaria de saber, de forma geral, quais são as principais causas dessa diferença de desempenho/interação entre o modo Debug e o modo release. Abaixo o código utilizado para a consulta.

```
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int n = 1; n <= numVar; n++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(n-1)))
                        {
                            resultados[n - 1].Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(n - 1)));
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            resultados[n - 1].Add(0); 
                        }



                    }
                }

                progressBar1.PerformStep();
```

E os queries utilizados são, geralmente, desse tipo:

```
     SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000251), 2), 
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000258), 2),
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000265), 2),
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000272), 2),
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000279), 2),
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000286), 2),
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000293), 2),
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000300), 2),
  ..
    ROUND(SUM(HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.VL_M4000398), 2)
     FROM HT_MA4_SBX_SEG WHERE HT_MA4_SBX_SEG.TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('13/07/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('14/07/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

As tabelas utilizadas tem, aproximadamente, 5.300.000 linhas de dados.

Comment: Tenta aprender sobre async await, o problema é que você executa todo o código no thread da interface, aí sempre que tiver algo demorado, vai congelar ela.

Comment: Faz total sentido. Vou dar uma olhada. Mesmo após a execução da parte demorada, a barra de progresso, por exemplo, não atualiza. Isso é normal? Valeu!

Comment: Provavelmente isto está relacionado ao tamanho dos dados. Não é para ficar lento só porque entrou em *release*.

Comment: Entendi. Executando uma das queries diretamente pelo MySql workbench ele demora cerca de 30s para retornar o resultado. No momento, o aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo tem que realizar códigos semelhantes cerca de 60 vezes.

Comment: Sim, o workbench sofre de um problema diferente, ele não virtualiza a interface ou se virtualiza é muito ruim, aí sempre que tem muitos dados ele engasga. Sobre a barra de progresso não atualizar as vezes é normal, pois você travou toda a renderização da tela e o winforms atualiza usando a message pump, pode ser que você esteja perdendo a mensagem de atualização nas engasgadas.

Comment: Faz alguns anos que não lido com winforms, então não lembro se possui virtualização no datagrid original, então ja te alerto, tentar mostrar 1 milhão de items sem virtualização vai travar a interface mesmo se o processamento tiver em outro thread.

Comment: Tranquilo. Os queries, na verdade, são do tipo que retornam apenas uma linha de valores. Seria possível, por exemplo, utilizar o recurso async para fazer a consulta MySql para deixar a interface menos engessada? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se retorna uma linha e está enroscando você está com sérios problemas.

Comment: Adicionei as partes principais do código para os colegas avaliarem se existe algum método ruim de aquisição dos dados via aplicativo.

Comment: Sim, o async vai permitir que a interface continue funcionando, as animações da barra de progresso e tudo mais não vão travar. Se possível crie caches dos sums obtidos, me lembra um sistema contábil que programei, queries desse porte são bem pesadas mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Como os colegas disseram nos comentários, o problema era que todo o código estava no mesmo thread, fazendo com o que o restante do form aguardasse sem poder ser modificado. 
Por fim, utilizei a classe [BackGround Worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Dentro do DoWorker coloquei toda a parte do código que faz a consulta mysql e trata o resultado. Tive alguns problemas em relação à quantidade de variáveis que pode ser repassada ao BackGround Worker, para resolver isso, utilizei a resposta dada [neste tópico(inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145780/alternative-to-backgroundworker-that-accepts-more-than-one-argument).
Agradeço a ajuda de todos.